# Associating string keys with int in nested dictionary

Tags: python

I'm trying to associate keys with a unique identifier. That is, transform dict1 to dict2:

```
dict1={'A': {'A': 1},
       'B': {'B': .5, 'C': .36, 'E': .14},
       'C': {'A': .5, 'C': .5},
       'D': {'G': 1},
       'E': {'F': 1},
       'F': {}
       }

dict2={1: {1: 1},
       2: {2: .5, 3: .36, 5: .14},
       3: {1: .5, 3: .5},
       4: {7: 1},
       5: {6: 1},
       6: {}
       }
```

I came up with something recursively but my code isn't working too well for nested keys. Any suggestions on how to fix the code or approach this problem?

```
def transform(d, count = 1):
    output={}
    for k,v in d.iteritems():
        k=count
        count = count + 1
        if isinstance(v,dict):
            v=transform(v, count)
        output[k]=v
    return output
```

Comment: 'A' has a value of 1 because it occurred earliest in the iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a few parts. First of all, you need to pass any conversion that you have already determined (e.g. `A = 1`) to your function when you call it recursively - otherwise you won't use the same replacement for the same key in the nested dictionaries. Also, you need some way to ensure that when you generate a new key, that key is used up and won't be used again. When you increment `count` in your function, this will only affect it within the current call to the function - any calls higher up the chain will keep using a lower `count`, and so keys will be used multiple times.

My attempt:

```
import itertools

def transform(d, key_generator=None, conversion=None):
    if key_generator is None:
        key_generator = itertools.count(start=1)
    if conversion is None:
        conversion = {}
    output = {}
    for k, v in d.iteritems():
        if k in conversion:
            k = conversion[k]
        else:
            next_key = next(key_generator)
            conversion[k] = next_key
            k = next_key
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            v = transform(v, key_generator, conversion)
        output[k] = v
    return output
```

Testing:

```
conversion = {}
transform(dict1, conversion=conversion)
print conversion

{1: {1: 1},
 2: {1: 0.5, 2: 0.5},
 3: {2: 0.36, 3: 0.5, 4: 0.14},
 4: {5: 1},
 5: {},
 6: {7: 1}}
{'A': 1, 'C': 2, 'B': 3, 'E': 4, 'D': 6, 'G': 7, 'F': 5}
```

Because of the undetermined iteration order of the dictionaries (and because, even if you sort the initial dictionary, `E` will be handled before `D`), this conversion is not quite what you were looking for, but it's pretty close.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! The ordering is not really an important matter as long as each key has a unique identifier so your function is perfect.